# Understanding Digital Multiplexing

Tags: multiplexer

As I understand it, digital multiplexers contain multiple inputs (2^N), one output, and N selector lines. The selector lines are used to select which input is mapped to the output line. I then understand that a demuxer takes a single input line and based on the selector lines maps the input to one of multiple outputs.
So, assuming the above is correct, my question is how does using a mux/demuxer pair to change 16 line parallel communication signal to 1 mux'ed signal, then back to a 16 parallel signal work? How would the demuxer know the selector signals to use to change the mux'ed signal back? Do you need to run the mux'ed signal line with the selector signal lines together so that the demuxer knows the proper mapping?

Comment: Well, to start with, they contain N selector lines and 2^N inputs, not the other way around.

Comment: My apologies, that is what I meant. Edited my original post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three scenarios that I see:

1. The selector lines would either to run **with** the data line (as you suggested)
2. The selection comes from an external entity that feeds into **both**, the MUX and DMUX
3. The selection lines are controlled by a synchronised entity e.g. a **clock** or a counter powered by a clock.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that I have an 4-bit counter at both the ends with the output lines of these counters connected to the select lines. Now what I need is a synchronous clock to do what I want.

This is called time division multiplexing (TDM) and for proper communication, the clock rate should be at least 16x times greater than the maximum signal rate.

Comment: I accepted the other guys answer, as his covered multiple methods. Though, I thank you for an explanation of TDM, that makes a lot more sense now. Too bad I can't upvote yet, otherwise I'd upvote your answer.

Comment: I don't have a problem with delayed vote. :-)

Answer (score 0):

How synchronisation is achieved depends on context.

Within a board or piece of equipment counters could be reset in common and clocked together, or address lines could be used in common at both ends. In the case of shared address lines they would be able to be shared amongst multiple multiplexers.

When communications is across a serial link or encoded in a higher order data stream USB or any of the many communications protocols, a means is required to regenerate the relative timing at each end. This could be done in a substantial number of ways but they share in common the ability to identify the frame start and the values of the individual bits (usually 2 level binary but not always).

---

**Related:**

Long (long long ) ago (thesis project) I built a system which accepted a large number of analog signals (from telephone lines) and multiplexed them to a lesser number of tone detectors. This was done with standard CMOS transmission gate multiplexers (CD4051 8:1) at each end combined to make an  N input x M output mux as required, where M of the N channels were gated onto the "bus" in selected time slots and output to M tone detectors. As this was all within the one piece of equipment reset signals and clocking could be distributed as required. Details grom dimmish, but it seems likely that each input channel could be assigned an address of an output tone decoder and its corresponding timeslot. A very basic sample and hold was provided on each mux output to reconstitute the signal.
The common bus of this system was 'fuin'to observe on a scope. If say a single sine wave was transferred it could be seen occupying time slots in space with slots of width of 1/Mth of the total frame time. Several signals at once could be observed. With many channels in use at once the bus appeared to be 'noise' with signals being transferred end to end transparantly.

A very simple example system with a serial link can be made with eg 2 x CD4051 as mux and demux and a counter at each end. 
For an 8 channel system the counter can be arranged so that a high on bit 4 produces a delay in the clock signal and eg a high on the bus so that the far end sees a continuous "1"/high. This high can be used as a counter reset so that counters reset and sync. Clocking can be derived from the data signal or sent separately.

Answer (score 0):

OK, this is rather old question, but I think it deserves an update.

> how does using a mux/demuxer pair to change 16 line parallel
>   communication signal to 1 mux'ed signal, then back to a 16 parallel
>   signal work?

The short answer - It doesn't.

The long answer - while you correctly described how multiplexer/demultiplexer work, you missed the intended use completely.

Converting parallel communication into serial and back is a task for different devices, called *serializers/deserializers*. Check out [SN65LV1023A and SN65LV1224B](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn65lv1023a.pdf) datasheets for an example.

Now, since the title of the question is "Understanding Digital Multiplexing" I'd like to elaborate on this one as well.

The mux/demux behavior you have described is most commonly associated with **analog** multiplexing. The lines are blurred, unfortunately, and you can find the same terminology used in different contexts. So, I'll give the definition I am using myself to avoid a lot of confusion.

The *analog multiplexer* is a device that connects one signal wire to one (or more) signal wires *without knowledge of the nature of a signal*. This, by the way, makes analog muxes suitable for many digital applications as well (although this often requires external biasing components). Some examples are switching between sensors with analog voltage outputs, connecting multiple serial channels to one UART port etc. You can think of analog multiplexer as a collection of mechanical switches, which means the voltage on the output will be very close to the voltage on input.

The *digital multiplexer* is a device that connects one communication channel to one of many communication channels while *maintaining communication integrity*. To do the latter the mux must know the protocol being switched and actively participate in it. One typical example is [TCA9548A](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tca9548a.pdf) I2C switch. You may notice that it acts as I2C slave on one side, and as multiple I2C masters on the other. You can find similar devices for just about any existing digital protocol. Also note, that "protocol" here does not have to be complex, it can be as simple as digital 0/1 levels. However digital switch will always condition this signal, so unlike analog switch, the voltage on output is not equal to the one on the input.